# When are classes too similar

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic

I would like to make report from sales data in a POS system.

So, I have a `ReportGenerator` that has a `List <Ticket>`
The `Ticket` class represents a registration in the cash register. This can be a `SalesTicket` (`DirectSalesTicket`, `InvoiceSalesTicket`,...) or `CashRegisterMovementTicket` for a registration of money leaving or entering the cash register without a sale (e.g. taking money to the bank).

`InvoiceSalesTicket` has a `invoiceNumber` which a `DirectSalesTicket`doesn't have. So I'm OK with having 2 different classes.

For `CashRegisterMovementTicket` I could make 2 classes (`CashInRegisterMovementTicket` and `CashOutRegisterMovementTicket`) that inherent from `CashRegisterMovementTicket`(which is a `Ticket`) that represent money that was added to the cash register or money that was taken out of the register.
That would make 3 classes, that do not really differ from one another internally.

When I want to generate a report with al the money that has been taken out of the cash register I can just take the `List <Ticket>` and only use the ones that are of the `CashOutRegisterMovementTicket` type.

Another example:

`SalesTicket` has `List <SalesLine>`

Some reports are based on `SalesTicket` that have a gift certificate
So I have `NormalSalesLine` and `GiftCertificateSalesLine`, both inherent from `SalesLine` but internally they are the same.

It feels like I have a lot of classes that are sometimes very similar.
What am I missing?

Comment: You'll know that your classes behave too similarly if you're duplicating the tests between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is fine, however if you had only a SalesTicket with a TransactionType property (Invoice, Direct Sales, Cash, etc.) then you can use that property in the report for display or filtering.

If you had some abstract method that is implemented differently across the various SalesTicket types (like CalculateTax()... ) then you had a good reason for multiple types.